# What is the proper way to delete a WebLogic domain?

Tags: weblogic

I'm trying to delete a domain on my weblogic server. Is it safe to just delete the corresponding folder (/user_projects/domains/**base_domain**) ?

Or do I have to use an uninstaller? If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the standard installation procedure, the `domain` is isolated from the product installation. Therefore, it is completely safe to just delete the directory containing the `domain`.

You might want to backup the `domain.xml` file, though, just in case you need to recreate it.

Comment: What about `domain-registry.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

With weblogic 12.2.1 the domain-registry.xml is found on this path-
\oracle\weblogic\12.2.1, just delete the domain entry (that needs to be deleted ) found in domain-registry.xml, after this step the weblogic domain can be deleted safely.